# How to blur the subject field in a compose mail inspector?

Tags: outlook, vsto

I have an Outlook VSTO 2010 add-in providing a button to insert text from a custom lookup, into the subject. The basics of this work just fine by grabbing the inspectors `CurrentItem` (*MailItem*) and appending to the Subject string.

Where it comes unstuck, is if the user is focused in the subject field, enters some text, then clicks the custom button to add some more text to the subject. The text that the user entered, isn't yet saved to the underlying `MailItem`, so manipulating `MailItem.Subject` ignores the users text.

I can work around this by saving the mail item before manipulating the subject, ensuring that the subject input field is saved to the object, but this is at odds with the standard Outlook behaviour, and could lead to a lot of un-sent drafts saved to the users mailbox. What alternatives are there? Anything that blurs the subject field would work (*I can't find a way to even do that*), but there might be a more elegant solution?